# Setting the index after merging with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, series

Executing the following merge

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(range(5, 10), index=range(10, 15), name='score')
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': (11, 13), 'value': ('a', 'b')})
pd.merge(s, df, 'left', left_index=True, right_on='id')
```

results in this data frame:

```
     score  id value
NaN      5  10   NaN
0.0      6  11     a
NaN      7  12   NaN
1.0      8  13     b
NaN      9  14   NaN
```

Why does Pandas take the index from the right data frame as the index for the result, instead of the index from the left series, even though I specified both a left merge and `left_index=True`? The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.merge.html) says

> left: use only keys from left frame

which I interpreted differently from the result I am actually getting. What I expected was the following data frame.

```
    score  id value
10      5  10   NaN
11      6  11     a
12      7  12   NaN
13      8  13     b
14      9  14   NaN
```

I am using Python 3.7.5 with Pandas 0.25.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what happens:

1. the output index is the intersection of the index/column merge keys `[0, 1]`.
2. missing keys are replaced with NaN
3. NaNs result in the index type being upcasted to `float`

To set the index, just assign to it:

```
s2 = pd.merge(s, df, how='left', left_index=True, right_on='id')
s2.index = s.index

    score  id value
10      5  10   NaN
11      6  11     a
12      7  12   NaN
13      8  13     b
14      9  14   NaN
```

You can also merge on `s` (just because I dislike calling `pd.merge` directly):

```
(s.to_frame()
  .merge(df, how='left', left_index=True, right_on='id')
  .set_axis(s.index, axis=0, inplace=False))

    score  id value
10      5  10   NaN
11      6  11     a
12      7  12   NaN
13      8  13     b
14      9  14   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not really fit my usecase. I want to preserve the index from the series, which is not always equal to range(len(s)). I edited my question to clarify this point.

Comment: @Hendrikto Should've just said so, you can set the index post-merge; see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with reset_index:

```
df = pd.merge(s,df, 'left', left_index=True, right_on='id').reset_index(drop=True).set_index('id').rename_axis(index=None)
df.insert(1, 'id', df.index)

    score  id value
10      5  10   NaN
11      6  11     a
12      7  12   NaN
13      8  13     b
14      9  14   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the index is not always equal to range(len(s)). I should have been more clear about that. See the edit to my question.

Comment: I updated to make that change so the answer is right

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not need the duplicated information in both the `id` column and the index, I went with a combination of the answers from cs95 and oppressionslayer, and did the following:

```
pd.merge(s, df, 'left', left_index=True, right_on='id').set_index('id')
```

Which results in this data frame:

```
    score value
id             
10      5   NaN
11      6     a
12      7   NaN
13      8     b
14      9   NaN
```

Since this is different from what I initially asked for, I am leaving the answer from cs95 as the accepted answer, but I think this use case needs to be documented as well.